# como converter funções MatLab para RStudio?

Tags: r, matlab

```
tempo=Seq;   
conc=NCelTotais;
coef_ini = [MaxCT 1 2]; 
coef=[];
OPTIONS = optimset('MaxIter',1000,'TolFun',0.001,'TolX',0.01);
coef = fminsearch(@funcaoerro_sigmoide,coef_ini,OPTIONS);
A=coef(1);
B=coef(2);
C=coef(3);
y = A*sigmf(tempo, [B C]);
fNCelTotais=y;


where:
**funcaoerro_sigmoide**

function erro = funcao_sigmoide(coef);

global tempo conc;

A=coef(1);
B=coef(2);
C=coef(3);

y = A*sigmf(tempo, [B C]);
erro1 = (conc-y).^2;

erro=sum(erro1);
```

Comment: Você deveria descrever melhor o seu problema para possamos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Há um pacote que faz isso, veja [matconv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matconv/index.html) e a respetiva [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matconv/vignettes/overallUse.html).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**

Tem que traduzir, vendo o que um codigo faz e implementando na outra linguagem.

**Mais detalhes:**

De fato, a sua pergunta não está muito clara, mas assumindo que você precise traduzir a funcão que você colocou acima para [r](/questions/tagged/r), não existe muito o que fazer. Talvez exista alguém que tenha algo similar em R, mas ainda assim você precisa descrever o que a funcão faz (é o erro de fit de uma funcão [sigmóide](https://se.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/sigmf.html)).

Existe um pacote [CRAN de R/MATLAB](https://cran.r-project.org/), mas é apenas uma interface para o MatLab, que precisa estar instalado no sistema. Não sei se é compativel com o RStudio.

Comment: Tentarei explicar melhor! Possuo um conjunto de dados experimentais que precisam ser ajustados por uma curva teórica (ex. sigmóide) através de mínimos quadrados. No MatLab tem o programa principal e sua função correspondente que calcula por mínimos quadrados.
**programa principal**
'tempo=Seq;   
conc=NCelTotais;
coef_ini = [MaxCT 1 2]; 
coef=[];
OPTIONS = optimset('MaxIter',1000,'TolFun',0.001,'TolX',0.01);
coef = fminsearch(@funcaoerro_sigmoide,coef_ini,OPTIONS);
A=coef(1);
B=coef(2);
C=coef(3);
y = A*sigmf(tempo, [B C]);
fNCelTotais=y;'

**subrotina**
descrita como funcaoerro

Comment: @MarcosSalvino Num comentário não é o melhor lugar pra colocar tudo isso. Recomendo fazer uma [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/269391/edit) na sua pergunta e adicionar a informacão relevante!

Answer (score -1):

Tentarei explicar melhor! Possuo um conjunto de dados experimentais que precisam ser ajustados por uma curva teórica (ex. sigmóide) através de mínimos quadrados. No MatLab tem o programa principal e sua função correspondente que calcula por mínimos quadrados. programa principal 'tempo=Seq; conc=NCelTotais; coef_ini = [MaxCT 1 2]; coef=[]; OPTIONS = optimset('MaxIter',1000,'TolFun',0.001,'TolX',0.01); coef = fminsearch(@funcaoerro_sigmoide,coef_ini,OPTIONS); A=coef(1); B=coef(2); C=coef(3); y = A*sigmf(tempo, [B C]); fNCelTotais=y;' subrotina descrita como funcaoerro

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta, não adicione uma resposta que não responde a sua pergunta.

Comment: Se você tem alguma dúvida, o [tour] e o [help] podem lhe ajudar em como editar.